# Call Puppet function from Puppet template?

Tags: puppet

As of 0.24.8, can a Puppet template call a Puppet function?

I can get similar functionality by calling the function in my manifest, assigning the return value to a variable, and then using the lookupvar('variable') in the template, but I'd like to cut out the middle man.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Inside templates you have access to a scope object. All of the functions that you can access in the puppet manifests can be accessed via that scope object, although not via the same name. Prepend `"function_"` to the beginning of the function name. For example, here I included one template inside another: `<%= scope.function_template("template2.erb") %>`

http://reductivelabs.com/trac/puppet/wiki/PuppetTemplating has great documentation about the scope object inside templates. For really deep information about template and functions you can look inside `lib/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb` and `lib/puppet/parser/functions.rb`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Word of caution to anyone using the template() function in a template: you still have to qualify it like you do in a puppet manifest (ie, scope.function_template("module/template.erb")).

Comment: It is possible to use a variable for the name of the template file to load for the template function call within the template?  E.g. `<%= scope.function_template("sites/$domain/config.erb") %>`

Comment: Absolutely. Just be mindful that you're working in Ruby, not Puppet's DSL, so the variable names (and interpolation rules) are different. Your string should be `<%= scope.function_template("sites/#{domain}/config.erb") %>`.

Answer (score 3):

Let me extend the question also to **custom functions**. Basically, you call custom functions the same way as built-in functions (using function_ prefix), but make sure you pass all params in an array:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:namegoeshere, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
    # ...
  end
end

<%= scope.function_namegoeshere(["one","two"]) %>
```

Please note it also works without the square braces on some Puppet versions. More info: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/functions_ruby_overview.html

Another important thing is there is a **bug** (or feature) in **Puppet 2.6 or older** where custom functions are **not auto-loaded** into the template scope. You need to load them *manually*, otherwise function wont be found!

```
<% Puppet::Parser::Functions::function('namegoeshere') %>
```

More info: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7991

Answer (score -3):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by a Puppet function, but puppet templates are embedded Ruby, so you can do anything in the templates that you can in Ruby.

Comment: Native puppet functions are things like fqdn_rand(), sha1(), tagged(), etc. Custom Puppet functions are stored under the modules/modulename/plugins/puppet/parser/functions/. Can these be called from within a template?